# NSOperation is not happening in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I created an NSOperation subclass to handle some zip archive operations. No matter what, if I override `-start` or `-main` this block of code always happens:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"I am in the main thread");
    return;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

I've tried adding this block:

```
- (void) start {  //also tried overriding main

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSLog(@"In main thread, trying again");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self start];
        });
        return;
        //hard working code etc...
        //cpu intensive zip operations...
    }
```

But this causes a crash, an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` violation pointing at the `dispatch_async` line.

Comment: Maybe I'm just totally misunderstanding this, but it looks like you'll have an infinite loop in your block, because you are calling start from inside itself. Are you adding the nsoperation to a queue, or are you calling start yourself?

Comment: @BenPious it's not an infinite loop, because when it's called from inside the `dispatch_async`, the condition (`[NSThread isMainThread]`) will be false.

Comment: Can you show (a) the creation of your `NSOperationQueue`; and (b) the adding of these operations to your `NSOperationQueue`? If you manually `start` them, they'll be on the main thread, but if you add them to a `NSOperationQueue` you create, they should not. According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW15) "when you call the `start` method of a non-concurrent operation directly from your code, the operation executes immediately in the current thread."

Comment: @DaveDeLong you are right, I did not read that carefully enough....

Comment: The given `start` method is perfectly fine. There is a problem elsewhere. Please show the _whole_ code of the start message, and the code where you start the operation.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry, I didn't mean to post this, I had it all typed out and then I solved it myself and thought I closed the browser. I was running the operations through the mainQueue. Thank you all for commenting on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> No matter what, if I override -start or -main this block of code always happens:

The main operation queue runs on the main thread. From the docs for [`+[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW21):

> The returned queue executes operations on the main thread. The main
>   thread’s run loop controls the execution times of these operations.

So, running in another thread is a matter of what queue you add the operation to, not how you write the operation's code. If you want your operation to run on a different operation queue, you'll need to create a queue of your own using

```
NSOperationQueue* aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

You can find an example in [Adding Operations to an Operation Queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW38) in the Concurrency Programming Guide.

> But this causes a crash, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS violation pointing at the dispatch_async line.

It sounds like `-[NSOperation start]` probably isn't re-entrant. Your code effectively executes the same method on two different threads. In fact, look at [the docs for `-start`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/start), it's obvious that your code won't work:

> You can call this method explicitly if you want to execute your
>   operations manually. However, **it is a programmer error to call this
>   method on an operation object that is already in an operation queue**
>   or to queue the operation after calling this method. Once you add an
>   operation object to a queue, the queue assumes all responsibility for
>   it. *[Emphasis added. -Caleb]*

In other words, don't do that.

Comment: I think the answer isn't an explanation of the OP's issue. Form the given partial code of the overridden `start` method it looks _perfectly_ fine regarding re-entrance. Whether NSOperation's own `start` method is re-entrant or not is irrelevant - since it MUST NOT be called anyway (e.g. via `[super start]` (and from the given code, it will not). Whether the operation is started _manually_ AND started via enqueuing it into an `NSOperationQueue` is NOT asserted by the OP. So, your emphasized text from the docs, may merely be a hint of a potential issue.

Comment: From a design perspective, it makes also perfect sense to encapsulate the "execution context" (say queue) into the asynchronous operation and make that _private_. A client of an asynchronous function should generally not specify the execution context where that operation runs on (as opposed to a possible completion handler where the client may specify the execution context).

Comment: Holy crap guys, I didn't mean to post this question. I had it typed out, but then I solved it on my own. I was running the operations through the mainQueue. I thought that I closed the browser without submitting, but I must have sent it in.

Comment: @JustinAmberson No harm done -- maybe it'll help someone else in the future.

Comment: Also, I've been subclassing NSOperation and overriding -start so I could add asynchronous code that uses delegate methods, while controlling execution state myself. Some of these I request to start on the main thread. Got mixed up when I went to do some actual background work.